# Inset box shadow doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get an inside shadow working on an input field in Chrome. Unfortunately, this doesn't really work out so far. You can view a jsfiddle over here: http://jsfiddle.net/XgsPT/2/

My CSS:

```
input {
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: 15px;
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}
```

And this simple HTML:

```
<input type="text" width="30">
```

But no shadow appears... (Chrome 24)

Answer (score 2):

Give border to input field and the box-shadow will finally work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jx8xF/

```
input {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #aaa;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #aaa;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #aaa;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;

}
```

Comment: Awesome! had a hard time on this

Answer (score 1):

The background color of the `input` is messing things up. Check out [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeroenheijmans/m5ybK/), with this change to the CSS:

```
input {
    /* ... rest as before ...*/
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, WebKit doesn't allow us to add box-shadow to form controls with native appearance. We need to remove the nativa appearance.

```
input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
}
```

Also, some CSS properties such as border and background imply -webkit-appearance:none.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than setting the background to transparent set it to white, or whatever colour you like, you just need to declare it and then it will work as it should